# Is there a way I can customize a Switch colors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

My code is using a standard switch like this:

```
<Switch HorizontalOptions="End" IsToggled="{Binding PbSwitch}" />
```

When displayed it looks like this for the on and off:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to customize this so I can set the background color of the switch to a different color in both iOS and Android.  I think this would require a custom renderer but I am not sure how to do that.

Problem with the solution proposed:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible to customize switch control. Please check this. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-and-use-a-custom-switch-control-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: We added a change color effect for the switch control in the Xamarin Community toolkit for easy use. Maybe you can try that https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/tree/dev/src/Effects/Effects/Switch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand clear what you want , you may need custom renderer to achieve this effect.

---

First, define a CustomSwitch in PCL with color BindableProperty(with it you can set value and use on different platforms)

#### CustomSwitch

```
public class CustomSwitch : Switch  
{  
   public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchOffColorProperty =  
     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchOffColor),  
         typeof(Color), typeof(CustomSwitch),  
         Color.Default);  

   public Color SwitchOffColor  
   {  
       get { return (Color)GetValue(SwitchOffColorProperty); }  
       set { SetValue(SwitchOffColorProperty, value); }  
   }  

   public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchOnColorProperty =  
     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchOnColor),  
         typeof(Color), typeof(CustomSwitch),  
         Color.Default);  

   public Color SwitchOnColor  
   {  
       get { return (Color)GetValue(SwitchOnColorProperty); }  
       set { SetValue(SwitchOnColorProperty, value); }  
   }  

   public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchThumbColorProperty =  
     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchThumbColor),  
         typeof(Color), typeof(CustomSwitch),  
         Color.Default);  

   public Color SwitchThumbColor  
   {  
       get { return (Color)GetValue(SwitchThumbColorProperty); }  
       set { SetValue(SwitchThumbColorProperty, value); }  
   }  

   public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchThumbImageProperty =  
     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchThumbImage),  
         typeof(string),  
         typeof(CustomSwitch),  
         string.Empty);  

   public string SwitchThumbImage  
   {  
       get { return (string)GetValue(SwitchThumbImageProperty); }  
       set { SetValue(SwitchThumbImageProperty, value); }  
   }  
}
```

#### Android

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.Android
{
public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer  
{  
    private CustomSwitch view;  
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Switch> e)  
    {  
        base.OnElementChanged(e);  
        if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null)  
            return;  
        view = (CustomSwitch)Element;  
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBean)  
        {  
            if (this.Control != null)  
            {  
                if (this.Control.Checked)  
                {  
                    this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);  
                }  
               this.Control.CheckedChange += this.OnCheckedChange;  
                UpdateSwitchThumbImage(view);  
            }  
            //Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchBGColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);  
        }  
    }  
      
    private void UpdateSwitchThumbImage(CustomSwitch view)  
    {  
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.SwitchThumbImage))  
        {  
            view.SwitchThumbImage = view.SwitchThumbImage.Replace(".jpg", "").Replace(".png", "");  
            int imgid = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(view.SwitchThumbImage).GetValue(null);  
            Control.SetThumbResource(Resource.Drawable.icon);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchThumbColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);  
            // Control.SetTrackResource(Resource.Drawable.track);  
        }  
    }  

  private void OnCheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)  
    {  
        if (this.Control.Checked)  
        {  
            this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);  
        }  
    }  
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)  
    {  
        this.Control.CheckedChange -= this.OnCheckedChange;  
        base.Dispose(disposing);  
    }  
}  
}
```

#### iOS

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp2.iOS
{
    class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null)  return;

            CustomSwitch s = Element as CustomSwitch;

            UISwitch sw = new UISwitch();
            sw.ThumbTintColor = s.SwitchThumbColor.ToUIColor();
            sw.OnTintColor = s.SwitchOnColor.ToUIColor();

            SetNativeControl(sw);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage in Portable

```
<local:CustomSwitch Margin="50" SwitchOnColor="Red"/>
```

Don't forget add xmlns(namespace) in Xmal

```
xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:YouAppName"
```

Comment: Hello Cole,  So it's a bit more clear for everyone, can you copy in a simplified version of the Android solution that just does the same SwitchOnColor and SwitchThumbColor. Also can you say what the common file would look like.  Thanks

Comment: This gives me an error saying the Type SwitchRenderer could not be found.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @Alan2 sorry，what is common file？

Comment: Hello Cole,  Can you copy in the code for the Android solution to complete the answer to the question.  I think that way it would be more complete in case one day that link was to become invalid.  Thanks

Comment: Cole, sorry can you ignore the comment about common file :-)  By the way I would like to change the switch background color to Red when the switch is on.  How would I set the Red color in iOS and Android.  Thanks

Comment: One more question.  You have <local:CustomSwitch but where is "CustomSwitch" declared?

Comment: I tried your code on iOS and it looks very strange.  I uploaded a couple of images of both the on and the off so you can see what I mean. Thanks

Comment: Found the problem.  I need to define thumb color as white :-)

Comment: Hi @ColeXia-MSFT I noticed you have are calling `view.SwitchThumbImage` in `Android` renderer but its not defined in the PCL class.

Comment: @iamsophia oh my mistaken .you can see it in that link above ,several properties are defined in customswitch, I just select two of them . and forget to delete the relvant code in android renderer.

Answer (score 1):

In a Xamarin.Form shared app (mine is release v.4.6) one can simply add a Color to the  OnColor(Toggled true background) and ThumbColor (circular toggle) properties.  This value accepts named colors, rgb, rgba, etc.

```
<Switch IsToggled="True" OnColor="Red" ThumbColor="#d9d9d9" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for IOS Xamarin Forms:

[Change Switch color in IOS Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073923/change-switch-color-in-ios-xamarin-forms/49105593#49105593)

I solved it using custom Render with next code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MySwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
namespace CheckMyBus.App.ios.Renderers
{
public class CustomSwitchRenderer: SwitchRenderer
{       
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        Element.Toggled += ElementToggled;

        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            UpdateUiSwitchColor();
        }
    }

    private void ElementToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateUiSwitchColor();
    }

    private void UpdateUiSwitchColor()
    {
        var temp = Element as Switch;

        if (temp.IsToggled)
        {
            Control.ThumbTintColor = Color.FromHex(ColorConstants.BlueHex).ToUIColor();
            Control.OnTintColor = Color.FromHex(ColorConstants.OblueLightHex).ToUIColor();
        }
        else
        {
            Control.ThumbTintColor =  Color.FromHex(ColorConstants.GrayHex).ToUIColor();
        }
    }
}
}
```

and in Android Xamarin Forms project its done using

```
<item name="colorAccent">#6495ED</item>
```

in style.xml for MainTheme.Base style.

So this looks like an easier solution than creating a custom switch, you just need something like this so `CustomSwitchRenderer` could work:

```
public class MySwitch: Switch
{
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<myControls:MySwitch x:Name="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my App.xaml styles:

```
<Style x:Key="MySwitches" TargetType="Switch">
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState x:Name="On">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{StaticResource OnColor}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{StaticResource OffColor}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Usage:

```
<Switch Style="{StaticResource MySwitches}" />
```

Easy and practical, without any cumbersome and unnecessary Custom Render.

Comment: thats nice, but you cant set the off color for example (or other platform specific properties)