# How to change style of switches in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

so using Xamarin Forms, for some reason I had an issue regarding the Action Bar, when hidden it would stop the functionality on a tablet device, but worked on a mobile device. Not sure why.

So I'm currently looking at alternative solutions, one is incorporating the Action Bar into the page, to prevent any further issues from occurring.

However, after styling the action bar, I have noticed that the following behavior happens.

Without styled Action Bar:

**Photo one (With styled Action Bar:**
[image: Photo one(With styled Action Bar]

---

**Photo two (With styled Action Bar)**
[image: Photo two(With styled Action Bar]

My styling file is as follows:

```
<style name="ScanCaptureTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ScanCaptureTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ScanCaptureTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ScanCaptureTheme.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ScanCaptureTheme.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#214478</item>
</style>
```

I am not exactly sure why this is happening and after googling to attempt to find a solution to adjust the styling of my switches from Photo two to Photo one again, I couldn't find anything.

Is there a way to strictly have the styling set to my action bar or better yet, how I would go about styling the switches to their default "look"?

Just as a precusor - this is a strictly Android Xamarin.Forms application, no need for an iOS solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How to change style of switches in Xamarin.Forms

`Switch` also defines `OnColor` and `ThumbColor` properties. The `OnColor` property can be set to define the Switch color when it is toggled to its on state, and the `ThumbColor` property can be set to define the Color of the switch thumb.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<Switch OnColor="Orange"
        ThumbColor="Green" />
```

For more, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/switch#switch-appearance .

**Besides**,you can also achieve this using custom renderer.

First, define a CustomSwitch in PCL with color BindableProperty(with it you can set value and use on different platforms)

#### CustomSwitch

```
public class CustomSwitch : Switch  
{  
   public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchOffColorProperty =  
     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchOffColor),  
         typeof(Color), typeof(CustomSwitch),  
         Color.Default);  

   public Color SwitchOffColor  
   {  
       get { return (Color)GetValue(SwitchOffColorProperty); }  
       set { SetValue(SwitchOffColorProperty, value); }  
   }  

   public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchOnColorProperty =  
     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchOnColor),  
         typeof(Color), typeof(CustomSwitch),  
         Color.Default);  

   public Color SwitchOnColor  
   {  
       get { return (Color)GetValue(SwitchOnColorProperty); }  
       set { SetValue(SwitchOnColorProperty, value); }  
   }  

   public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchThumbColorProperty =  
     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchThumbColor),  
         typeof(Color), typeof(CustomSwitch),  
         Color.Default);  

   public Color SwitchThumbColor  
   {  
       get { return (Color)GetValue(SwitchThumbColorProperty); }  
       set { SetValue(SwitchThumbColorProperty, value); }  
   }  

   public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchThumbImageProperty =  
     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchThumbImage),  
         typeof(string),  
         typeof(CustomSwitch),  
         string.Empty);  

   public string SwitchThumbImage  
   {  
       get { return (string)GetValue(SwitchThumbImageProperty); }  
       set { SetValue(SwitchThumbImageProperty, value); }  
   }  
}
```

#### Android

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.Android
{
public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer  
{  
    private CustomSwitch view;  
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Switch> e)  
    {  
        base.OnElementChanged(e);  
        if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null)  
            return;  
        view = (CustomSwitch)Element;  
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBean)  
        {  
            if (this.Control != null)  
            {  
                if (this.Control.Checked)  
                {  
                    this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);  
                }  
               this.Control.CheckedChange += this.OnCheckedChange;  
                UpdateSwitchThumbImage(view);  
            }  
            //Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchBGColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);  
        }  
    }  
      
    private void UpdateSwitchThumbImage(CustomSwitch view)  
    {  
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.SwitchThumbImage))  
        {  
            view.SwitchThumbImage = view.SwitchThumbImage.Replace(".jpg", "").Replace(".png", "");  
            int imgid = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(view.SwitchThumbImage).GetValue(null);  
            Control.SetThumbResource(Resource.Drawable.icon);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchThumbColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);  
            // Control.SetTrackResource(Resource.Drawable.track);  
        }  
    }  

  private void OnCheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)  
    {  
        if (this.Control.Checked)  
        {  
            this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);  
        }  
    }  
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)  
    {  
        this.Control.CheckedChange -= this.OnCheckedChange;  
        base.Dispose(disposing);  
    }  
}  
}
```

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48516159/10308336 .